# ActiveResource trying to access a 2 times nested url 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, activeresource, unfuddle

This is the url I need to access

`/api/v1/projects/{id}/tickets/{id}/time_entries`

and this is my Project ActiveResource model so far ... I can get projects and tickets based on every project and I want to get every time_entrie based on tickets

```
class Project < ActiveResource::Base
self.site = "https://xyz.unfuddle.com/api/v1"

def self.get_time
  Project.all.each do |project|
    project.get(:tickets).each do |ticket|
      #from here I want to get to time_entrie
      #after the last_edit 
      TimeEntry.addparams({project: project.id,ticket: ticket["id"]})
    end
  end
end
```

Is this possible with only one ActiveResource model or do I need to make somekind of association between Project and another ActiveResource Ticket  ?

//although I haven't seen anything about associations on the rails api documentation.

//Edit
I've added a new TimeEntry ActiveResource model
that looks something like this

```
class TimeEntry < ActiveResource::Base
  self.collection_name="time_entries"
  def self.addparams(params)
    self.site = "http://xyz.unfuddle.com/api/v1/projects/#{params[:project]}/tickets/#{params[:ticket]}/"
    self.all
  end
```

Now if I run Project.get_time I get

```
ActiveResource::Redirection: Failed.  Response code = 302.  Response message = Found. => https://xyz.unfuddle.com/projects/38664/tickets/6336/time_entries
```

Comment: What happen if you try `self.site = "https://xyz.unfuddle.com/api/v1/projects/#{params[:project]}/tickets/#{params[:ticket]}/"` ?

Comment: sorry didn't saw the 's' :P .. it seems it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so final answer I needed https instead of http and I needed to implement 2 ActiveResources like I specified in the question .